# Blender 2.81: Transfer rig to similar unrigged, unskinned model

Tags: rigging

I have 2 models:
Model #1 is rigged and skinned and animated (with over 50 different animation fbx files):

[image]

Model #2 is not rigged and not skinned.
[image]

I would like to use the animations of Model #1 on Model #2.

I would need to adjust the bone positions so that it would work on model #2.

How could I transfer the rig of model #1 onto model #2?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: If you can upload a blend with decimated versions of the characters, I would prepare a step by step answer.

Comment: @Leander Thank you, I will do that. Give me 10 minutes.

Comment: The prefered plattform for sharing is to upload your (small) blend to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and the add the link to your question with an edit. And if there was a test animation, that would also be beneficial.

Comment: @Leander Done, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I renamed the armature *model1* to *rig1*. I suggest you adapt a naming system which differentiates between armature/rig objects and geometry/mesh objects.

#### Preparation

To better see the armature during the process, I select *rig1*, active **In Front** and choose **Wire** for the *display as* property. This way the rig is always visible in front in wireframe mode (less in the way but clearly visible).

[image: x axis]

Next I will create a T-Pose like action (take), to which I can always switch to if I modified some transformations.

1. Select the rig1.
2. Go into *Pose Mode*.
3. Select all bones. <kbd>A</kbd>
4. Clear all transformations. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>
5. Press <kbd>I</kbd> to open up the *Insert Keyframe Menu* and choose LocRotScale to insert the appropriate keyframes.

[image: t-pose]

Open up the dopesheet editor (1), and switch to the *action editor* (2) mode. Here you can see the keyframes we created with the <kbd>I</kbd> hotkey and also the action which was automatically created. Different actions can be stored independently from rigs in the blend. To preserve the action, even we do not need it, create a "*fake user*" for it (3) by clicking on the shield icon next to the action name. In the action dropdown, you can also see the other action *Armature.001|Loco_Walk|BaseLayer* which the other armature referers to.

[image: dopesheet]

I renamed both actions and made sure they both have fake users. With the  Rig selected, we can preview both actions by selecting them in the action editor. They have an **F** next to their name, if they have a fake user.

As both actions are protected now, I delete the unused additional armature.

[image: actions]

#### Create the other armature

Select the armature *rig1* and duplicate it by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> in the 3D Viewport. In the outliner, there will be the duplicated *rig.001*. Hide the original model and original rig, by clicking on the [disable in viewport](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/outliner.html#restriction-columns) icon (TV symbol).

[image: objects disabled]

I rename the duplicated rig to *rig2*.

Briefly unhiding *model1*, I select *model2* and position it as close as possible on top of the *model1*. I am in right orthographic view and eyeball the position while using the transform tools, <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>.

Then I go to the properties panel and open up the modifier section. We will use a data transfer modifier to transfer the weight groups from *model1* to *model2*.

1. Select *model2* and add a [*Data Transfer*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/modify/data_transfer.html) modifier to it.
2. Choose *model1* as the source object (4).
3. Enable Vertex Data and Vertex Groups (5), then choose *Nearest Face Interpolated* as the transfer method. (6)
4. Make sure the evaluate in global space button is checked (7).

[image: data transfer]

Clicking on Generate Data Layers (8) will generate the needed vertex groups.

[image: vertex groups]

If all vertex groups have been created, **Apply** (9) the data transfer modifier and hide the original *model1*.

The vertex weights have now been transferred to *model2* and can be examined in [Weight Paint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/weight_paint/index.html#weight-paint) mode.

[image: weight]

#### Connect the armature

With the weights already transfered, we only need to connected armature. Select *model2* and <kbd>Shift</kbd>select *rig2* in the 3D Viewport. It is important that rig2 is the active object. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>P/kbd> to open up the parent menu. Choose Set Parent To *Armature Deform*

[image: parent]

This will parent *model2* to *rig2* and add an armature modifier.

*model2* should now move if we assign the *walk* action to *rig2* in the action editor.

[image: transferred]

This is how far transferring the weights and armature goes, since the object vary in their shape.

The next steps are

- manually reposition bones of the *rig2* armature in edit mode
- correct the weights of *model2* in weight paint mode
- add new bones and new weights

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! What an amazing tutorial!! Please give me so time to go through it.

Comment: Could you please tell me what you mean by "by selecting them in the action editor"? I don't see how I could switch from seeing the created keyframes to seeing the model to preview it. Thank you!

Comment: I'm talking about [this gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYpiu.gif). [1] Select the rig. [2] Go to the dopesheet > action editor. [3] Open the desired action from the dropdown menu. [4] Playback to see the animation.

Comment: How do you show the preview next to the frames? Here is what I see: https://i.postimg.cc/hG2yrWTq/pig2.jpg

Comment: By [splitting an area](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/167111/30849) and opening the 3D View and the Dopesheet side by side.

Comment: Would you willing to take a look at my video? I have recorded my Data Transfer. I have tried it from scratch a few times, but the weights won't transfer, my model is always blue. Thank you. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLGAj-K-aUE

Comment: Select the vertex groups in weight paint mode. You will only see the weights of the currently selected group. If then, still, all weights are blue, maybe unhide the model1 before applying the data transfer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107854/discussion-between-tmighty-and-leander).

Comment: Can I ask one last question, please? Why are the bones so strangely positioned pointing outside the mesh and not completely inside the mesh like for example in this tutorial? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rG82fogtuCg

Comment: It happens when the bones axes are not set accordingly during an fbx import. Search for "fbx import, bone orientation, forward/up axis"

Comment: Thank you. I have checked "Automatic Bone Orientation" during fbx import now, and that fixed it. Thank you again. I'm totally new to animation, and your tutorial was suuuuuch a great, motivating kickstart. Thank you!

Comment: I'm having a problem with the bone orientation even with "Automatic Bone Orientation". I have posted a new question about this here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/178117/blender-2-81-how-do-i-import-the-rig-correctly     If you feel like posting there, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Would it be possible to simply import the new mesh into the old file and then link the object data from the newly imported mesh to the existing, rigged mesh? Is this a viable workflow? What kinds of difficulties would this bring, and how could they be addressed? If this approach could be made to work, it would save a ton of effort.

Comment: Yes, this is a viable workflow. But you would *"newly imported mesh to the existing, **armature**"*. Meshes are connected (linked) to armature with the armature modifier. For a bone of the armature to influence a mesh, there are has to be a corresponding armature modifier on the mesh and a **vertex group, *with the same name***. [See this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/128950/30849).